# Accessing Dropbox Datastore database

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I use an outdated iOS app called Loggr, and now would like to extract data stored in it. It syncs with Dropbox Datastore, which I can see on my Dropbox account:

[image: Loggr Datastore indication]

But I cant find any files corresponding to among my Dropbox files. My question, how do I extract the information from the Datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox Datastores are a structured data storage system, separate from files, so they won't appear as files in your account. They should be available under "Apps you use" here though:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/datastores